# why are my primitives see through?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

i am rendering a 3d surface in opengl by drawing a bunch of triangles. some of my primitives are see through. i don't simply mean that there is a blending of the color behind them, i mean that i can see completely through them. i have no idea why i am able to see through these primitives and would not like that to be the case (unless i specify alpha blending which i have not).

unfortunately i cannot link any code (there are ~1800 lines right now and i don't know where the error would be!), but any help would be great.

i hope i have given enough information, if not, please feel free to ask for me to clarify!

EDIT: more info ...

i call plotPrim(ix,iy,iz) which uses cube marching to plot a triangle (or a few) through the current cube of a rectangular grid.

myInit() is ...

```
void myInit()
{
// initialize vectors
update_vectors();
// set initial color to white
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glEnable(GL_BLEND | GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

plotMesh() is where i do my work of going through each cube and plotting the primitives

```
void plotMesh()                             //
{
if(plot_prop)
{
    // do some stuff
}
else
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for(int ix = 0; ix < snx-1; ix++)
    {
        //x = surf_x[ix];
        for(int iy = 0; iy < sny-1; iy++)
        {
            //y = surf_y[iy];
            for(int iz = 0; iz < snz-1; iz++)
            {
                //z = surf_z[iz];

                // front face
                a = sv(ix+0, iy+0, iz+0);
                b = sv(ix+0, iy+1, iz+0);
                g = sv(ix+0, iy+0, iz+1);
                d = sv(ix+0, iy+1, iz+1);
                // back face
                al = sv(ix+1, iy+0, iz+0);
                be = sv(ix+1, iy+1, iz+0);
                ga = sv(ix+1, iy+0, iz+1);
                de = sv(ix+1, iy+1, iz+1);

                // test to see if a primitive needs to be plotted
                plotPrim(ix, iy, iz);

            }
        }
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

}

one example of a primitive being plotted in plotPrim() is ....

```
if(val>a && val<g && val<b && val<al || val<a && val>g && val>b && val>al) // "a" corner
{
    tx = (val-a)/(al-a);
    ty = (val-a)/(b-a);
    tz = (val-a)/(g-a);

    x1 = surf_x[ix] + tx*surf.dx;
    y1 = surf_y[iy];
    z1 = surf_z[iz];

    x2 = surf_x[ix];
    y2 = surf_y[iy] + ty*surf.dy;
    z2 = surf_z[iz];

    x3 = surf_x[ix];
    y3 = surf_y[iy];
    z3 = surf_z[iz] + tz*surf.dz;

    getColor( (1.0-tx)*sv(ix,iy,iz) + tx*sv(ix+1,iy,iz) );
    glVertex3f(x1,y1,z1);
    getColor( (1.0-ty)*sv(ix,iy,iz) + ty*sv(ix,iy+1,iz) );
    glVertex3f(x2,y2,z2);
    getColor( (1.0-tz)*sv(ix,iy,iz) + tz*sv(ix,iy,iz+1) );
    glVertex3f(x3,y3,z3);
}
```

Comment: If you can't share any code, perhaps you can add more details. As it is now, this question is very vague. What operating system are you on? What version of OpenGL are you using. What kind of graphics card do you have? What windowing system are you using?

Comment: Do you have back face culling enabled? If so, some polygons may not be drawn, depending on the order you defined their vertices.

Comment: Most likely your z-testing or culling is not doing what you're expecting. Include the code where you're setting up the render state (which shouldn't be long), i.e. where you're calling `glCullFace`, `glEnable(....)` and so on.

Comment: if you're not already, consider inserting regular calls to glGetError, to see if anything is going astray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND | GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

is wrong as [`glEnable`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml) only takes a single capability to enable, not a bitmask. You might have more errors, but you want to change the above to:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```